# Conditionally adding to dictionary without updating tuple value

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

The function append below takes a pair which is an immutable tuple as a parameter.  In the processing of the append it is necessary to enclose all values with start and end single quotes.  Because the tuple values are immutable I cannot simply do this:

```
if item[1][0] != "'" and item[1][-1] != "'":
    item[1] = "'{0}'".format(item[1])

 self.keyvalues[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Hence the handling as follows:

```
if item[1][0] != "'" and item[1][-1] != "'":
    self.keyvalues[item[0]] = "'{0}'".format(item[1])
else:
    self.keyvalues[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Full code appears below.

Is there a more elegant way to add the key and value to the dictionary.

```
class section(object):
    """class to hold a section. name is name of section. keyvalues is a key
     value dictionary of keys and values"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.keyvalues = {}
        print "Constructed section:", name

    def append(self, item):
        """add a key value pair to section"""
        if len(item) != 2:
            return False
        else:
            print "adding:", item, "to", self.name, "object"

            # cannot do this because tuple is immutable
            #item[1] = "'{0}'".format(item[1])

            # Would there be a more elegant way of doing this - given that
            #  parameter must be a immutable tuple?
            if item[1][0] != "'" and item[1][-1] != "'":
                self.keyvalues[item[0]] = "'{0}'".format(item[1])
            else:
                self.keyvalues[item[0]] = item[1]
            return True

    def __repr__(self):
        s = "contains\n"
        for k, v in self.keyvalues.iteritems():
            s += "\t{0}={1}\n".format(k, v)
        return s

    __str__ = __repr__    


mysection = section("section1")
dnpair = ("key1", "value1")
mysection.append(dnpair)

print mysection
```

Comment: The way you are doing it is fine.  An "elegant" solution is purely a subjective basis.

Comment: @StackofPancakes Yes probably true but I am relatively new to Python so wondered if I was missing out on some useful idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tuple is not used again, just split it to separate variables.

```
key, value = item

if value[0] != "'" and value[-1] != "'":
    value = "'{0}'".format(value)

self.keyvalues[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant is subjective, but this is the most elegant solution I could come up with.  It allows value manipulation by passing it off to a function.  Also the ugly

```
if item[1][0] != "'" and item[1][-1] != "'":
```

becomes

```
if not value[0] == value[-1] == "'":
```

Here's the full code with the modified `append` and newly created `quote_wrap` method.

```
def append(self, item):
    """add a key value pair to section"""
    if len(item) != 2:
        return False
    else:
        print( "adding:", item, "to", self.name, "object")
        self.keyvalues[item[0]] = self.quote_wrap(item[1])
        return True

def quote_wrap(self, value):
    if not value[0] == value[-1] == "'":
        value = "'{}'".format(value)
    return value
```